# The arbitrariness of metrics in probability theory

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

I know in to some extent the role of measures in statistics. However, in other regards, I am kind of lost.

In trying to understand Mahalanobis distance, I asked at various places how to understand it. Besides some intuitive explanations of what it gives me, I also got the following answer:

"It's simply a metric."

That makes me wonder how you can decide what metric can be used in probability theory. I was given some variants of the answer above, and that makes me wonder how you can determine if a metric is useful in determining the probabilites of some things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what I am seeing is two questions: (1) What is the Mahalanobis distance good for?  and (2) How does one choose a metric when one is needed?

I think, (1) is answered in the "Applications" section of the Wikipedia article on the Mahalanobis distance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance#Applications  Basically, having a sample point and several probability distributions, one can use the Mahalanobis distance to "guess well" which distribution the point is most likely to have come from.

As for (2), the choice of a metric (and, more generally, of a mathematical model) in any application (not just in probability theory) is rather an art than a science.  You first look at the goals (i.e., what you would like to get out of the model), and then choose the mathematical machinery that, you feel, best takes towards those goals.  So, the process is intuitive.  The only rigorous part of is the posterior testing of how well the model does what we want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

"That makes me wonder how you can decide what metric can be used in probability theory."

I find that a very soft question, since the broadness of the context is not specified in any other way than "probability theory". Different metrics arise several parts of probability theory and they have a wide range of purposes. Mahalanobis distance is (usually) a metric on $\mathbb{R}^d$ defined by some sample, so I'll restrict my answer to those types of things.

In $\mathbb{R}$ we may say that $x$ is "$n$ standard deviations away" from the mean. This is what you do when you normalize your normally distributed observations. Mahalanobis distance can be seen as a kind of a multivariate generalization of that. The distribution can be stretched differently to different directions so "one standrad deviation away" is not really sufficient: you also need to worry about the direction. That's why Mahalanobis distance produces elliptical contours that are squeezed according to how the distribution deviates to different directions.

Now, what kind of metrics make sense? Some people (like [Carlsson in his paper](https://www.math.kth.se/math/GRU/2013.2014/SF2704/Papers/Topologyanddata.pdf)) argue that metrics are not theoretically justified. I think that, from the statistician's point of view, this is a question that doesn't really have a sensible general answer, but boils down to understanding the data you are dealing with and choosing your methodology accordingly.